# No Launcher Activity Found even though there is

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-launcher

This is a copy of my AndroidManifest.xml
Any help as to why the launcher is not being recognized? I tried running the code without applying DEFAULT to any other activity but it's still not working.

```
    enter code here

    <application
        <activity
            android:name="project.shirsho.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="project.shirsho.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="project.shirsho.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.Textplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TEXTPLAY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Assuming you want the Splash `Activity` as your launcher then change its category in the intent-filter to `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` and remove that category from your Menu `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the MAIN and LAUNCHER in the the intent filter for the activity you want to start on launch by :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

if you want that Splach Activity as your launcher , your manifest must be :

```
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="project.shirsho.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.Textplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to make "project.shirsho.Menu" as the launcher activity, then it should be like:

```
<activity
        android:name="project.shirsho.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

change,

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="project.shirsho.MENU" />
```

to

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how your application part should look like. If you use eclipse to develop in it will help you create this (androidManifest.xml)

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```